# Should I be installing Windows 8 drivers or Windows 7 drivers on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, drivers

So I just reinstalled Windows 7 on my laptop to get rid of all the bloatware it came bundled with.

Now I will need to install Ethernet Drivers, because Windows 7 itself doesn't seem to have any proper drivers for the Ethernet card in my laptop.

When I stumbled upon the driver download page (It's an Acer laptop by the way), I noticed that - when I select Windows 8 as the OS - it actually gives me a newer version of the LAN drivers.

(Windows 7, LAN: 1.0.2.43) https://imgur.com/LOBPO7I

(Windows 8, LAN: 2.1.0.7) https://imgur.com/13oV2bY

So since I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop, should I use the Windows 7 drivers or should I use the Windows 8 drivers? (Because they seem to be newer)

Or could there be compatiblity issues or something?

Answer (score 1):

> should I use the Windows 8 drivers?
>
> could there be compatiblity issues or something?

**No**, and basically both questions have the same answer.

Porting or Modding Drivers is possible but there you have a lot of reasons to avoid to use that in your machine:

**Compatibility.**

It could make your healthy system work improperly because the drivers is not developed to run over a newer system.

**Inestability.**

The Driver could work but it could start to affect another devices, or damage the hardware.

**Testing.**

The old driver is builded to work with an especific O.S and it haves a lot of testing.

---

I could told you a few more reason to avoid to do that, but it is inneccesary, but i suggest you to answer for yourself this question.

**Why i should use a ported driver whitout any test, with unknown compatibility and with a lot of inestability only because is newer than older one??**

> Answer: you have no reasons, stay with the current stable driver.